# Android is killing my app "Force finishing activity". How to debug?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have the following log output

```
W/ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.x.y/.MainActivity
```

and no other warnings/errors from my app itself or anything that gives me a hint in a direction for me to debug what is causing the issue.

I only now that this behaviour comes when I scroll down a `RecyclerView` list that is backed by firestore and loads data through paging.

It does not matter if I scroll the list fast or slowly the app will crash without any further error with the above log message.

How to debug a behaviour that is caused by the system?

**Update**
I did not find the problem yet. Although I do not have the feeling that it is memory related. I did override `onTrimMemory`. This is the outcome:

```
2022-07-08 17:28:50.826 2779-2779/x.y D/MainActivity: onTrimMemory: TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_MODERATE
2022-07-08 17:29:07.051 3257-3257/x.y D/MainActivity: onTrimMemory: TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_MODERATE
```

This was logged during startup. When I enter the list of elements that leads to the crash **no** new trim message appears. Also I used the profiler to monitor ram usage up to the crash. It does not look suspicious at all. So I am a bit lost again where to look next, as the app is still crashing.

[image: RAM profiler]

What I did notice though: If I scroll my list slowly, my app crashes at exactly the same position in the list. If I scroll fast, I can see more elements before the crash but this also might be because the system needs time to shut down the app.

Comment: Share your sample code.. might be others can provide solution.. place log overirides method destory stop somewhere

Comment: What sample code? I have thousands of lines of code and cannot narrow it down besides that it happens with `RecyclerView` - But I will try to narrow it down by commenting out code sections. If I find anything I will post - I think one possibility could be some kind of memory leak. What do you mean by "log override method" ?

Comment: LifeCycle based put some logs you can identify something... You've to share proper details otherwise others can't help you..

Comment: I was hoping for some general hint like "ah yah you definetly have a memory leak there. That is the normal log message in that case". I try to narrow it down (I mean that is what I am doing anyway alongside this post). Any updated I will share here. I will also include lifecycle logs, good hint

Comment: Try overriding the life-cycle callback in your activity `onTrimMemory(int level)` and diagnose the `level` using: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory - see also https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-management#low-memory_killer for the logic behind which apps may be stopped.

Comment: I tried to profile my memory and added an update on the issue. Although I am more stuck than before now. Any further ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It had nothing to do with memory management whatsoever.

My Testdevice just did not show the error log (I do not understand why though!). Using a different Device I finally got the error stack trace and could narrow down the mistake